# How can I replace ?myuser=number with an empty string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

How can I replace a string containing a lot of `?myuser=12122` `?myuser=5457` `...` with empty string so that it doesn't show `?myuser=number` inside the string?

I think I should use regex?

Comment: Just a Hint: You get the best answers by stating "I have this" and "I want it to look like that"

Comment: Thank you dbemerlin for your suggestion, i will try to implement it in my future questions :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes,

```
 preg_replace('~\?myuser=\d+~', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 3):

The question mark is a special character in regular expressions, so you must quote it. Apart from that, it's quite straight forward:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\?myuser=[0-9]+/', '', $source);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = preg_replace("/\?myuser=(\d+)/iU","",$yourstring);
```

Comment: `\n` is a new line. `\d` are numbers.

Comment: ...which is easy to remember if you stop thinking of _numbers_ but instead think of it as _digits_